# What's a good video camera to use while running?

Tags: video-camera

I'm interested in creating a video for my cross country team, including several shots while I or another runner am/is in motion. My teammates and I quickly thought of a GoPro camera, but most are extremely expensive compared to our price range (we'd like to stay under <strike>$50</strike> $75).

What is a good camera for us?

The specifications we'd like to see:

- The camera should be mountable either on a lightweight hat or strapped around the upper chest of a runner
- The price should be under <strike>$50</strike> $75
- The camera mounting system must be able to survive leaps, jumps, turns, etc. The runner with the camera may reach speeds of up to 12 miles per hour while running on trails with hilly terrain, so jostling will be an issue.
- A weight under half a pound
- 1080p resolution
- A 180 degree viewing angle
- A battery life of four hours

We're willing to sacrifice one of the latter three if necessary, but the top two are non-negotiable.

Comment: 180 degrees is some serious fisheye you've got there.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Very much so. We'd like to play around with the recording a bit, to get an interesting view of what it's like (or not like) to run. I also put that there partly because I wasn't entirely sure where to draw the line.

Comment: To put it in perspective, human visual field is 200 degrees laterally (160 per eye), of which just 17 degrees are in any kind of detail. An average camera uses 60 degrees field, and a fisheye can be 100 degrees.

Comment: Would you be willing to go a little higher on the price? Maybe like under $75? I'm not sure you can actually get a good camera for under $50.

Comment: Honestly, an iPhone might be able to work, although you'd need some DIY setup for mounting and all that. Figured this because pretty much everyone already has an iPhone or something similar.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you the Mobius Action cam.

[image: Picture of the mobius action cam]

> The camera should be mountable either on a lightweight hat or strapped around the upper chest of a runner

You can buy Magnet Mounting Clip for hats and the most basic package of the camera usually comes with a mounting sleeve with lots of options.

> The price should be under <strike>$50</strike> $75

It's around $70 on eBay and Banggood.

> The camera mounting system must be able to survive leaps, jumps, turns, etc. The runner with the camera may reach speeds of up to 12 miles per hour while running on trails with hilly terrain, so jostling will be an issue.

I bought mine for cycling and I use it in the city and offroad as well without any issue with the velcro hooks on my helmet. I don't have any experience with another mounting systems but I guess usual head straps are good enough for a small and lightweight camera like this.

> A weight under half a pound

It's only 37 gramms.

> 1080p resolution

It's supported, 30 fps.

> A 180 degree viewing angle

I don't think that this is currently available in this price range.
[Mobius (with the new C lens) has 132 degrees.](https://www.mobius-actioncam.com/mobius-adds-new-wide-angle-c-lens/)

> A battery life of four hours

[New versions comes with 820mAh battery](https://www.mobius-actioncam.com/store/products/mobius-replacement-battery-820mah/) which provides more than two hours of recording. I was able to record 140 minutes (1080p, 30fps) with my camera in the first few months. (I have not tested since then.) With a small power bank you can extend the battery life and it might be still below your weight limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a phone, this might work for you.

[image]

<sup>Moustache recommended, but sold separately.</sup>

> The camera should be mountable either on a lightweight hat or strapped around the upper chest of a runner

Not sure if it's a hat... It looks more like a... Freaky headband used to brainwash people, and slow your fellow runners.

> The price should be under $50 $75

$34.99 on sale for just $18. That's half off :)

> The camera mounting system must be able to survive leaps, jumps, turns, etc. The runner with the camera may reach speeds of up to 12 miles per hour while running on trails with hilly terrain, so jostling will be an issue.

I haven't tested that, nor will I ever probably want too. But it's got a case!

> A weight under half a pound

It's 90 grams. Is that less than a pound?

> - A 180 degree viewing angle
> - 1080p resolution
> - A battery life of four hours

Mobile phone sold separately. Depends on what phone you've got, let's hope it has a fish eye :)

---

[image]